# Table is not partitioned in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The table in Big Query says that it partitioned table but data is not getting stored in different tables based on date.

[Table not Partitioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lyjn.png)

[Expected Partitioned Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQvWS.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not partitioning; when BigQuery shows tables with a date picker in this fashion it is because they are *sharded*.

To shard a table give it the same name, with a different date suffix, for example:

- `my_data_20210101` and `my_data_20210102` will be sharded.
- `my_data_20210101` and `my_data_2_20210101` will NOT be sharded.

See the official docs here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard